# How to pass a variable to sqlplus in a bash script

Tags: oracle, bash, sqlplus

I have a script like below. My goal is write to a log file terminating with the current date and time as filename and spool to the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

year=`date +%Y`
month=`date +%m`
day=`date +%d`
prefixe=$month$day$year
logfile="/home/oracle/logs/exec_proc_daily_20_"$prefixe.log

sqlplus / "as sysdba" <<EOF
spool on
spool $logfile
execute Proc_RFC_MAJ_MV_ITIN;
execute Proc_RFC_MAJ_MV_REFGEO;
commit;
quit
EOF
```

When I execute the script, the `spool $logfile` gives an error. No log is created. But it works when I use something like `spool exec_proc_daily_2o.log`. Why is the variable `$logfile` not replace.

Comment: Replacing `sqlplus / "as sysdba"` with `cat` and running your script suggests that the variable replacement _is_ working as expected...

Answer (score 3):

[Edited with working example] Pass a variable to sqlplus:

demo.sh

```
export myvar1="hello"
export myvar2=123
sqlplus "/ as sysdba" @demo.sql $myvar1 $myvar2
echo "---shell is complete---"
```

demo.sql

```
select 'first variable is &1 and second is &2'
from dual;
exit
```

Comment: Hi @Beege. Thanks for your input. I've tried your approach but it doesn't work. I get the message of incorrect usage of sqlplus command with suggestions on how to use it.

Comment: works in linux env, I have made two changes as I don't like to refer $1 and $2 in my SQL script.
```
define myvar1='&1'
define myvar2='&2'
select 'first variable is &&myvar1 and second is &&myvar2'
from dual;
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

After doing alot of digging, I found the solution to the problem. On the line `sqlplus / "as sysdba" <<EOF`, I passed the variable like this `sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF >$logfile`. So the complete code should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

year=`date +%Y`
month=`date +%m`
day=`date +%d`
prefixe=$month$day$year
logfile="/home/oracle/logs/exec_proc_daily_20_"$prefixe.log

sqlplus / "as sysdba" <<EOF >$logfile
spool on
spool $logfile
execute Proc_RFC_MAJ_MV_ITIN;
execute Proc_RFC_MAJ_MV_REFGEO;
commit;
quit
EOF
```

Comment: Your sqlplus command is redirecting the output of sqlplus to the $logfile.

Answer (score 1):

@Beege answer works in Linux env. I have made few changes as I don't I like to refer to &1 and &2 in SQL script everywhere.

```
myvar1="hello"
myvar2=123
sqlplus username/password@SID @oracle_variabling_passing.sql $myvar1 $myvar2
echo "---shell is complete---"
```

oracle_variabling_passing.sql:

```
define first_var=&1
define second_var=&2
select 'first variable is &&first_var and second is &&second_var'
from dual;
exit
```